# SQL Server join table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SQL Server database with two tables as below. The first one is called "Goal_Group" and the Second one is called "Goal".(Original tables has fields more than this). Every goal has a goal group. The two tables are linked (have a foreign key) by GGID.

```
**Table Goal Group**
GGID   | GGNAME      | GGDESCRIPTION
1        operational   operational description
2        development   development description

**Table Goal**
GID    | GNAME       | GGID
1        test1         1
2        test2         1
3        test2         1
4        test2         1
```

I want to create a view to display all the goal with their goal groups. The view should be like below.

```
**Final View**
GID    | GNAME   | GGID    | GGNAME
```

But even though the goal table doesn't have any row with GGID of 2, I want to have a row in my view for goal group of GGID=2 with null values to othe fields.
When I create a view with left join like below,

```
select b.GID, b.GNAME, a.GGID, a.GGNAME from GOAL_GROUP a
left join GOAL b
on  a.GGID=b.GGID
```

it doesn't give me a row with GGID of 2.

Am I doing something wrong. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: yes it's because, your Goal table GGID are 1 for all data, if you change any of them to 2 then both records come..

Comment: Your query works correct, You do not have any problem with it. Try to find another issue with your tables

Comment: Any way, add this condition to your query and let us know about the results: `where b.GGID is null OR b.GGID is not null`

Comment: are you absolutely certain this is the full query. Do you by any chance also have a `where` on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the outer Join on GOAL table with matching key with GOAL_GROUP table:

```
select b.GID, b.GNAME, a.GGID, a.GGNAME from GOAL_GROUP a left outer join GOAL b on  a.GGID=b.GGID
```

or, if you want to do things manually(I won't suggest this):

You can insert the actual results in some temp table and put the extra row in temp table with GGID=2 like this way:

```
 select * into #temp from (select b.GID, b.GNAME, a.GGID, a.GGNAME from GOAL_GROUP aleft join GOAL bon  a.GGID=b.GGID)

DECLARE @GGID2 int=select  a.GGID from GOAL_GROUP a where a.GGID=2

insert into #temp (GID, GName, GGID, GGNAme)  values(null, null,@GGID2 , null)

select * from #temp
```

just make sure the table Goal can accepts null values because we are creating same structure for temp table. If not, create the tamp table manually.
Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the outer clause in your statement:

```
select b.GID, b.GNAME, a.GGID, a.GGNAME from GOAL_GROUP a
left outer join GOAL b
on  a.GGID=b.GGID
```

another way to accomplish the result

```
select b.GID, b.GNAME, a.GGID, a.GGNAME from GOAL_GROUP a,
 GOAL b
where  a.GGID*=b.GGID
```

HTH

Comment: I also tried left outer join and it does not work for my problem. What is the use of * in the second example you were given. It doesn't work properly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: the * is for bringing all the records of one side that don't have a counterpart, is just another way of expressing the outer join.  Could you try with right outer instead of left outer, unfortunately I'm not near a SQL Server, to test the answer, I apologize for that

Comment: it gives me the following error.

Msg 4147, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
The query uses non-ANSI outer join operators ("*=" or "=*"). To run this query without modification, please set the compatibility level for current database to 80, using the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE. It is strongly recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN). In the future versions of SQL Server, non-ANSI join operators will not be supported even in backward-compatibility modes.

Comment: The * can be used in one side or the other depending which is the table that you want to be fully scanned (or used as base for the outer join)

Comment: go for the `left outer join` or `right outer join` instead, again, maybe is just the direction of your join and you just need the `outer` clause, you can even disregard the direction and use `full outer join`, this one will bring data from both sides with nulls in the other when there is no join and the joined records.    HTH

Comment: `left outer join` = `left join`. outer is optional `*=` syntax is generally frowned upon and avoided for good reason